# TCPDF Link is not working with Mac PDF Preview

Tags: php, macos, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am generating a PDF with [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) that has some internal linking. For example, on page 1 I used the following code to jump on a specific point on some other page (say page 10).

```
$pdf->Link($linkX, $linkY, $w, $h, '#reference');
```

On page 10, I made that reference destination using the following code,

```
$pdf->setDestination('reference');
```

This way when I click on the link on page 1, it jumps to page 10 where I put the destination reference. This works fine with Adobe Reader, Chrome, Edge PDF viewer. But it doesn't work on Mac Preview. Can anyone tell me why this is happening only with Apple Mac Preview but works fine with all other PDF viewers?

Comment: Maybe Apple Mac Preview does not support this kind of links in PDF in general?

Comment: I am guessing that too. But do you have any reference that tells me this kind of link is not supported by Mac preview?

Comment: I came across https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4144259, suggesting Apple might have removed functionality related to this, although that is from 2012 already.